# Replace unknown character � in BigQuery query using Airflow

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, airflow, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to read a BigQuery table and turn it into a pandas dataframe using Python on Airflow.
This is the code I'm using to execute the queries:

```
bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=SRC_CONN, use_legacy_sql=False)
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project = bq_hook._get_field("project"), credentials =bq_hook._get_credentials())
df = bq_client.query(SQL_QUERY).to_dataframe()
```

(I'm using the Bigquery Storage v1 API Library)

If the query returns any string field with the unknown character � I get the following error:

> ERROR - Unknown error: Wrapping <string_with_�_char> failed

In my case, these characters only ever appear on one column.

If I exeute the query on the BQ console, i can see the results with the � character, but if I run it on Airflow, the DAG crashes because it can't read � character.
I have tried to replace the � character with an "@" using these solutions, but none seem to work:

- The .replace() Python function: it won't work because, due to the previus
  error, the dataframe can't be fully created, so I can't do any futher handling.
- the BQ function REGEXP_REPLACE: I can't replace the � character with the query; if I use REGEXP_REPLCACE, it ignores the � character (as a matter of fact, if I try to get the length of the whole string, it doesn't count the � character).

So basically I need some way to correct this issue that can be applied on the third line of the code I posted previusly; maybe a parameter of the .to_dataframe() function or one that can be applied right after it.

Comment: you may want to look at the encoding of the dataframe, by default BigQuery I believe utf-8 encodes, you'll likely need to match the encoding on the df.

Answer (score 0):

`BigQueryHook` has [get_pandas_df](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/25a50bb1fbf0e228706c7927cb36570921881adb/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L204) function.

You can do:

```
bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=SRC_CONN, use_legacy_sql=False)
bq_df = bq_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=SQL_QUERY, dialect="standard")
# continue work on the data frame
```

As for crashing - there is no reason for this code to crash. If this happens there is probably a bug and you should report it on [Airflow issues](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues).

Comment: I tried using get_pandas_df before, but it gives the error: ERROR - The private_key argument is deprecated. Construct a credentials object, instead.
I´m working on a shared server, so I don't think I can downgrade to a previus version of the BQ library